# Start iterating csv file from a given row onwards?

Tags: python, csv

I was in the process of iterating a large csv file and collecting data based on the userIds of that large csv file. Lets call this file as `file_A`. In the middle of the process my machine crashed. But  Now I want to kick start the process again but only want to proceed beyond the last record that I collected:

I wrote a simple methods to get the last row of the results file:

```
def get_last_row(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        lastLine = reader.next()
        for line in reader:
            lastLine = line
        return lastLine
```

Now I want to iterate over file_A beyond line return by evaluating the results file. How can I do this?

```
for row in input_file:
  if row != lastLine[user_id]
     make a database call
```

this is wrong because it will consider all the lines other than the lastLine.

lets assume this example

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
```

lets assume `lastLine['user_id']` is `3`, I want to continue processing the starting from record with 4

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is wrong about that approach -- aside from a missing `continue` statement...

Comment: I agree with @bernie, only thing I can think of would be to put `if row[user_id] != lastLine[user_id]` so that you're comparing apples to apples?

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: @martineau where is the link for the duplicate question?

Comment: @Null: It's right at the top of your question. BTW, if you want to read until the end-of-file, but don't know how many lines there are in the file, you can pass `islice()` the value `None` as the _`stop`_ (third) argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways to do that. First is to use a condition variable and test it on each operation => produces a clean and easy to maintain code with little repetitions :

Assuming your current code looks like :

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # optional initialization ...
    for line in reader:
        # process line
```

You just do :

```
skip = True
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # optional initialization ...
    for line in reader:
        if skip:
            line[user_id] = last_line_user_id
            skip = False
        else:
            # process line
```

Alternatively, you can choose to separate one first loop to skip already processed lines from actual line processing :

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # optional initialization ...
    for line in reader:
        if line[user_id] == last_line_user_id:
            break
    for line in reader:
        # process line
```

You duplicate loop code, but have no test in the processing part